# Cannot querySelector in my Polymer component

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to access to a part of my component by querySelector, but it return null.

My html in my component looks like :

```html
<nav class="mainmenu">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="dropdown" id="my-dropdown">
```

The reason I want to access this, is because, I want to change classes in certains conditions when user click somewhere in body.

```dart
void ready(){
 document.body.onClick.listen((E)  {
   if(_isActive){
    querySelector("#my-dropdown");
```

the querySelector always retun null. Why ?

I understand shadow dom forgive me to access in other dom component, but why in the same component ?
How can I access to it ? Or maybe I should process differently ?

Comment: Try shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-dropdown'). This means querySelector will select the element within the shadow dom of your element, not the publicly visible dom which is what this.querySelector() does.

Comment: You can also use this writing to select by id within a PolymerElement:
var dropdown = $['my-dropdown'];

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use `querySelector("#my-dropdown")` you are using the top level function [querySelector](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html#id_querySelector). This function search in the main document and not inside the ShadowDOMs of the polymer elements.

In your case you should use `shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-dropdown')` or `$['my-dropdown']` (it's a shortcut) to get the element you are querying.